# OpenDDS Error in Running Messenger Example

Tags: publish-subscribe, publisher, subscriber, data-distribution-service

**EDIT:** I have switched from DCPSInfoRepo to RTPS, and everything is working fine. I don't know if this question should stay open to answer the problem for anyone working with DCPSInfoRepo

---

I am looking into using OpenDDS, and I am currently following the "Getting Started" guide for Windows. I reached the step of running the Messenger example using the command

```
run run_test.pl
```

I get the following output which I believe is an error.

```
C:\dds\bin\.\DCPSInfoRepo.EXE -ORBDebugLevel 10 -ORBLogFile DCPSInfoRepo.log -o
repo.ior
TAO (5508|6556) - Did not find default svc.conf
TAO (5508|6556) - Completed initializing the process-wide service context
TAO (5508|6556) - Default ORB services initialization begins
TAO (5508|6556) - Default ORB services initialization completed
TAO (5508|6556) - We are the default ORB ...
TAO (5508|6556) - Initializing the orb-specific services
TAO (5508|6556) - ORBInitializer_Registry::register_orb_initializer 0 @007F95C0
.\.\publisher.EXE  -ORBDebugLevel 10 -DCPSDebugLevel 10 -ORBLogFile publisher.lo
g
.\.\subscriber.EXE  -ORBDebugLevel 10 -DCPSDebugLevel 10 -DCPSTransportDebugLeve
l 6 -ORBLogFile subscriber.log
ERROR: publisher returned 4294967295
ERROR: subscriber returned 4294967295
INFO: C:\dds/bin/DCPSInfoRepo being killed.
```

Can I please get some directions on how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Have you checked the log files that are created, publisher.log, subscriber.log, and dcpsinforepo.log?

Comment: @JohnnyWillemsen Yes, I have. But they are very long and complex, I don't really understand the content. What should I be looking for?

Comment: Lines with error, probably related to hostname and ip address, check whether you can ping your system using its DNS hostname

Comment: I have switched from DCPSInfoRepo to RTPS, and everything is working fine. I don't know if this question should stay open to answer the problem for anyone working with DCPSInfoRepo

Comment: I personally would go for RTPS and completely forget the DCPSInfoRepo

Comment: @JohnnyWillemsen do you have aby good resources on how to actually start a new OpenDDS project from scratch? I have understood the examples given, but I couldn't find resources on starting your own project. The guide only contains snippets. Thanks.

Comment: No, documentation of OpenDDS is limited, did you have a look at RTI Connext DDS?

Comment: My colleague is taking a look at it. I'm the one stuck with OpenDDS. Do you recommend it as opposed to OpenDDS? and why?

Comment: @alhadhrami, how do you switch to RTPS ?

Comment: @Twimnox, to run the `publisher` and `subscriber` in RTPS mode, you don't start the `DCPSInfoRepo', run the 'subscriber' and 'publisher' with '-DCPSConfigFile`  `RTPS` configuration. For example `./subscriber -DCPSConfigFile rtps.ini` and the `rtps.ini` should contain configuration details as `[common]
DCPSGlobalTransportConfig=$file
DCPSDefaultDiscovery=DEFAULT_RTPS

[transport/the_rtps_transport]
transport_type=tcp`